# Fiddler regex to match a file

Tags: regex, web, pattern-matching, fiddler

I am trying to intercept a http request(which is requesting for a .js file) and return a file from the local disk.

Here are the sample `http` requests :

```
> http://rupall.mmk.test.com/%7B636242121790000792%7D/WebResources/main_system_library.js?ver=1854333973
> http://rupall.mmk.test.com/%7B636242121790000792%7D/WebResources/main_system_library.js?ver=1854333973
> http://rupall.mmk.test.com/%7B636242121790000792%7D/WebResources/main_system_library.js?ver=-1518765574
```

Here is my regex :

```
REGEX:http://rupall\.mmk\.test\.com/.*/WebResources/main_system_library.js?ver=.*$
```

But this regex is not matching any of the http requests that I listed above. When I use the test feature of fiddler, it is failing. Is this regex correct or what am I missing here ?

[image: Fiddler regex test]

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/4zoky6/1

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> ***`https?:\/{2}\w*\.\w*\.\w*\.\w*\/{1}\%\d\w*\%{1}\d+\w\/{1}\w*\/{1}\w*\.js\?ver\=`***

***https://regex101.com/r/4zoky6/1***

> [image]